# Communicating between services in a project (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine

If I deploy two services (REST apps) to the *same project* in google app engine, I can access those from the outside, but I get 403 - Forbidden if I try to perform REST calls between the services. How should this be configured ?

Answer (score -1):

It's only firewall configuration and ingress settings (default ingress setting is that a service allows all access) that make up "inter-service" communication in a project, it seems. So as long as the firewall is not blocking your services internally, they should be able to communicate.